# How can I copy sequential parts of vim file into new files and naming those files with dates?

Tags: date, vim, macros, filenames, date-arithmetic

I have files that are 100000+ lines in length.

I would like to take the first n lines, cut them, and paste them into a new file named s20130115.txt (that representing the starting date), then save and close the new file.
Then I would like to take the next n lines, cut them, and paste them into a file named 20130116.txt, then save and close the new file.

The I would like to continue that process until the original file is empty.

Any thoughts?

TIA

Comment: That looks like a non interactive task, maybe a script would be a better solution?

Comment: A related question http://superuser.com/q/485189/133552.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you'll want to do this with `awk` or some other scripted editing tool instead; it will save you a lot of repetition.  So I'm going to assume you can't for some reason; maybe the number of lines is different each time and there's no better way to tell than just by looking.

You can write lines from your file into a new file using the `:w` command with a range.  For instance:

- If you type `10:w foo.txt`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will take ten lines starting at the cursor position and write them to the file "foo.txt".  You can then delete those 10 lines with `10dd`.
- You can type `:1,10w foo.txt`<kbd>Enter</kbd> to write lines 1-10 of your file to "foo.txt" (counting from the start of the file, regardless of cursor position).  Delete by entering `:1,10d`<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- You can select a range of lines by pressing `V` and moving the cursor.  Once the range is selected, type `:w foo.txt`<kbd>Enter</kbd> to write the lines.  Select the same range again with `gv`; then you can delete with `d`.